# How to crash a react native android app

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am working on react-native-firebase crashlytics. I am using rnfirebase starter kit. There we have crashlytics integrated with the project. Now, I want to crash my app to check the crash report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You need to import packages react-native-fabric and another line in initial file.

```
import Fabric from 'react-native-fabric';

var { Crashlytics } = Fabric;
Crashlytics.crash();
```

Answer (score 7):

It is now:

`import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';`

then

`crashlytics().crash()`

https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage

Answer (score 4):

You need to need to import the crashlytics and use crash() to do a manual crash.

```
import crashlytics from 'react-native-fabric-crashlytics';
```

Calling the code below should crash your application:

```
crashlytics().crash();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import crashlytics and use crash() to do a native crash.

```
import crashlytics from 'react-native-fabric-crashlytics';
crashlytics().crash();
```