# How to crash react native app on purpose?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have already seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641661/8140312), but I don’t want extra packages on my hand
I have also tried to `throw` exception but it was quite slow and created many other problems, all I want is a piece of code that just crashes the app

Comment: what about making any null pointer exception or division by zero ? Does not that work?

Comment: `while(1)` works every time

Comment: or just `console.log(a);` Crash : `a is undefined`.

Answer (score 8):

TypeScript

```
  const test: any = {};
  console.log(test.should.crash);
```

Will cause

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'test.should.crash')

Answer (score 4):

Consider that you can't crash app on development. these answers cause crash on production releases only

Comment: I crash ALL THE TIME in dev mode...?

Comment: @ShepSims I don't work with react native now-days, at that moment it didn't crash on development. no idea about the latest version in case it's your meant.

Answer (score 2):

just add any string outside of a `<Text/>` block

i.e.

```
<View>hello world</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can crash the app by requesting Camera without adding the key NSCameraUsageDescription in Info.plist. It'll crash the app without warning.